# Styling jQuery script output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here’s the code

```
 <script>
function get_price(){
        var price_margin = 0.00174;
        jQuery.get("https://min-    api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?    fsym=XRP&tsyms=USD").then(function(data){
        jQuery('#xrp_price').text(function(price){
            return "PRICE " + data["USD"].toFixed(5);
        });
    .......
```

That returns a value 0.45678 for e.g but I’d like to make the last 3 digits really small so just the 0.45 stands out. 
I have tried changing the .text to .html and adding  or  but that just makes the whole value bold and not the last 3 digits. Hmmmmmm (scratches chin).
All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Instead use `.toFixed(5);` set it to `.toFixed(2);` :https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: I need to keep 5 decimal places though, just the first 2 bold or regular size with the remaining 3 smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead set `.text` set `.html`

and set the 3 first chars in `span` with `class='bold'`

and the other chars get by use  `data.toFixed(5).slice(3)` and set another `class='small'`

then style in css according classes in html

```js
    var data=0.45678 ;
    $('#xrp_price').html(function(price){
        return "PRICE <span class='bold'>" + data.toFixed(2) + "</span> <span class='small'>"+ data.toFixed(5).slice(3) + "</span>";
    });
```

```css
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.small{
font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xrp_price"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
You can use `<small>` DOM instead `<span class='small'>`

Comment: Excellent! Works a treat. Can it be done within the script itself without using spam? For instance using <small> to make the last 3 digits smaller?

Comment: of course you can I wull update answer(I use class to style as you want like color...)